# Using Google maps API on local network

Tags: api, google-maps, mobile, local

I'm thinking of developing a software, which has following features :

- Runs on desktop, connects with other software (MS Flight Simulator).
- Acts as a web server, opens a TCP socket and receives HTTP request, and returns HTTP response (including Google Maps API).
- User can connect to that server with web browser of mobile devices(Android, iPhone, iPad, ...) on local network(e.g. 192.168.0.1:8080), so Google map is displayed.
- It will be a free software.
- I also want to add AdSense Library on the map.

There are similar apps such as FSXFollow or FsMovMap. But it'll be better if user doesn't have to install native apps and just uses web browser.

I found following statements in terms of use :

9.1 Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation.

9.1.1 General Rules.

(b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not operate (i) only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

I wonder if I can use it. 
If not, is there any way to get a permission?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an aside, how do you plan to make sure that your connecting devices have the maps if they do not have an internet connection?

Comment: Connecting devices should have its own internet connection. It's just that the webpage including google map is sent from a local server, not from a public internet server. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how it is on iOS, but on android, if you are connected to a wireless network, your "own internet connection" won't be used.

Comment: The internet connection is wireless via home router, so it can connect to PC and internet at the same time.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but when I turn off the internet connection at my router (in the router control panel), my Android phone doesn't realize this and it will still try to get web resources over the wifi whenever it is connected. Technically, it could use its own internet connection to take over, but it just doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a lot of Google API do not work if you are not directly connected to the Internet (for instance, the one to create charts using javascript).